# Android Studio -- include "Menu option" in "Create Activity"

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

When I try to make a new Blank Activity in Android Studio, it lets me *glance* at the screen that would let me include a Menu Resource Name, and then... that disappears and I get one without that option.
    I went in to Gradle  and changed my minSdkVersion to 21 in case that was an issue (or does it need to be 23?), but that didn't help. 
    I've been creating the menu in the resource folder on my own, and adding the code that's in my other activities (which I *think* Android Studio willingly created for *those* activities), but I'd like to be able to let Android Studio do it for me, and as I'm still very new at this, it makes me nervous to try to get Android Studio to do something it doesn't seem to think it should do.
     What determines whether or not an activity includes a menu resource?  Thanks...